# Ipad Chrome Downloading Zip file doesnt work

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, ipad, ionic-framework, gzip

I have an asp.net web page which is within a secure area of my website.

There is a list of files where you can select a number of them and click on a button which will then put those files in to a zip file that the user will be asked to download.

It does not work correctly when im using an ipad and chrome. It redirects to a blank page and shows the name of my aspx page. Ipad and safari is fine. Desktop and Chrome is fine.

If i go directly to a zip file it downloads correctly on the ipad and chrome but not if the webpage creates the zip file on the fly.

Below is the code im using. Does anyone know why? Have been stumped for a week. I am using a dll called ionic.zip.dll

```
protected void btnDownload_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ArrayList arrayZipFiles = new ArrayList();

    //Loop throug all rows in the Files grid looking for which records are checked
    foreach (GridDataItem gdiFiles in gridFiles.MasterTableView.Items)
    {
        CheckBox chkSelected = (CheckBox)gdiFiles.FindControl("chkDownload");
        if (chkSelected.Checked)
        {
            //Add to the ArrayList
            String strFullFilename = gdiFiles.Cells[6].Text.ToString();
            arrayZipFiles.Add(strFullFilename);
        }
    }

    //Pass ArrayList to function which pushes in to Zip and initiates the download 
    if (arrayZipFiles.Count > 0)
        DownloadFiles(arrayZipFiles);
}

protected void DownloadFiles(ArrayList arrayZipFiles)
{
    if (arrayZipFiles.Count > 0)
    {
        String strOrderNo = String.Empty;
        foreach (GridDataItem gdiItem in gridOrders.SelectedItems)
        {
            //Get order No to use as filename for zip file
            strOrderNo = gdiItem["OrderNo"].Text.ToString();
        }

        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + strOrderNo + ".zip");
        using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            foreach (string strItemToZip in arrayZipFiles)
            {
                zip.AddFile(strItemToZip, "");
            }
            zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
            Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Has anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Has anyone got any ideas?